# Apache to tomcat proxy is not working

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

I have got apache 2.4, and 1 tomcat (connector port - 8081 and AJP - 8009) server (both on same linux box) on which I have an application folder named 'MyApp' in webapps directory.

Tomcat direct URL is - http://localhost:8081/MyApp/MyApp --> This links loads fine and displays the images, jquery and js works fine.

I am proxying all the requests to tomcat from apache using mod_proxy as mentioned below -

ProxyPass /MyApp ajp://localhost:8009/MyApp/MyApp

ProxyPassReverse /MyApp ajp://localhost:8009/MyApp/MyApp

Now, when I try to access it through web server URL, the URL loads but the images, css, jquery, which are inside the /u01/tomcat/webapps/MyApp directory doesnt work.

If I try to load the direct URL of the image, for example - http://localhost/MyApp/images/logo.jpg it doesnt work,

In the body of the image, I see -

HTTP Status 404 - /MyApp/MyApp/images/incidentReport.jpg 
See above line, it is adding one more ''MyApp' to fetch the image

On the other hand, the tomcat URL [ localhost:8081/MyApp/images/logo.jpg ], loads fine.

What could be the issue? The developer of the application has designed it in such a way that it should work with a double 'MyApp' i.e. localhost:8081/MyApp/MyApp

What else do I need to do either on webserver/tomcat in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps:

**Step 1:** Before configuring Apache, you should enable the necessary modules.

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

**Step 2:** Next, you are going to modify the default configuration file `000-default.conf` inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` to set up "proxying" functionality.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8081/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 3:** Next, you are going to modify the server.xml file.

```
<Host name="www.drew-jocham.com" appbase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                 directory="logs"  prefix="resumesite_log." suffix=".txt"
                 pattern="common"/>
        <Context path="" docBase="/MyApp/MyApp" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>

</Host>
```

Once you are done with your configuration, you will need to restart the cloud server for the changes to go into effect. Execute the following command to restart Apache: `service apache2 restart`

And that’s it!

Read more: https://medium.com/@ldclakmal/deploy-a-java-web-application-in-digitalocean-882226dcdbd5